# FSCalendar range selection - Swift

Tags: swift, fscalendar

Now i have the code working properly for the range selection but for the range selection i need only the start and end dates were highlighted with background colour , in between dates should be shaded something like layer , so i need to use the FSCalanderCell for that , i don't know how to implement that prepared cell to this controller based on my need could anyone help out of me from this task

```
class CalanderViewController : UIViewController {
    
    private weak var calanderView: FSCalendar!
    
    private var datesRange: [Date]?
    private var firstDate: Date?
    private var lastDate: Date?
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupNavigationBar()
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupNavigationBar() {
        self.navigationItem.title = "Calendar"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, .font: FontFamily.Poppins.bold.font(size: 15)!]
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "",style: .plain,target: nil,action: nil)
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        let calanderView = FSCalendar()
        calanderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        calanderView.dataSource = self
        calanderView.delegate = self
        calanderView.scrollDirection = .vertical
        calanderView.placeholderType = .none
        calanderView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        calanderView.weekdayHeight = 20
        calanderView.today = nil
        calanderView.calendarHeaderView.isHidden = false
        calanderView.register(RangePickerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        let appearance = calanderView.appearance
        appearance.titleDefaultColor = .black
        appearance.calendar.rowHeight = 0
        appearance.titleFont = FontFamily.OpenSans.semibold.font(size: 11)
        
        view.addSubview(calanderView)
        self.calanderView = calanderView
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.calanderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            self.calanderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor , constant: 20),
            self.calanderView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor , constant: -20),
            self.calanderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
        ])
    }
    
    func datesRange(from: Date, to: Date) -> [Date] {
        if from > to { return [Date]() }
        
        var tempDate = from
        var array = [tempDate]
        
        while tempDate < to {
            tempDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: tempDate)!
            array.append(tempDate)
        }
        
        return array
    }
}


extension CalanderViewController: FSCalendarDataSource , FSCalendarDelegate {
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        // nothing selected:
        if firstDate == nil {
            firstDate = date
            datesRange = [firstDate!]
            
            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
            
            return
        }
        
        // only first date is selected:
        if firstDate != nil && lastDate == nil {
            // handle the case of if the last date is less than the first date:
            if date <= firstDate! {
                calendar.deselect(firstDate!)
                firstDate = date
                datesRange = [firstDate!]
                
                print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
                
                return
            }
            
            let range = datesRange(from: firstDate!, to: date)
            
            lastDate = range.last
            
            for d in range {
                calendar.select(d)
            }
            
            datesRange = range
            
            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
            
            return
        }
        
        // both are selected:
        
        if firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil {
            for d in calendar.selectedDates {
                calendar.deselect(d)
            }
            
            lastDate = nil
            firstDate = nil
            
            datesRange = []
            
            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
        }
    }
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didDeselect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        // both are selected:
        
        if firstDate != nil && lastDate != nil {
            for d in calendar.selectedDates {
                calendar.deselect(d)
            }
            
            lastDate = nil
            firstDate = nil
            
            datesRange = []
            print("datesRange contains: \(datesRange!)")
        }
    }
}


//Cell ========>



enum SelectionType {
    case none
    case today
    case single
    case leftBorder
    case middle
    case rightBorder
}

class RangePickerCell: FSCalendarCell {

    public weak var circleImageView: UIImageView!
    public weak var selectionLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    public weak var roundedLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    public weak var todayLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    var selectionType: SelectionType = .none {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        let selectionLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        selectionLayer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        selectionLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(selectionLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
        self.selectionLayer = selectionLayer

        let roundedLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        roundedLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        roundedLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(roundedLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
        self.roundedLayer = roundedLayer

        let todayLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        todayLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        todayLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        todayLayer.actions = ["hidden": NSNull()]
        self.contentView.layer.insertSublayer(todayLayer, below: self.titleLabel?.layer)
        self.todayLayer = todayLayer

        self.shapeLayer.isHidden = true
        let view = UIView(frame: self.bounds)
        self.backgroundView = view
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.selectionLayer?.frame = self.contentView.bounds
        self.roundedLayer?.frame = self.contentView.bounds
        self.todayLayer?.frame = self.contentView.bounds

        let contentHeight = self.contentView.frame.height
        let contentWidth = self.contentView.frame.width

        let selectionLayerBounds = selectionLayer?.bounds ?? .zero
        let selectionLayerWidth = selectionLayer?.bounds.width ?? .zero
        let roundedLayerHeight = roundedLayer?.frame.height ?? .zero
        let roundedLayerWidth = roundedLayer?.frame.width ?? .zero

        switch selectionType {
        case .middle:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let selectionRect = selectionLayerBounds
                .insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 4.0)
            self.selectionLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(rect: selectionRect).cgPath

        case .leftBorder:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let selectionRect = selectionLayerBounds
                .insetBy(dx: selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 4)
                .offsetBy(dx: selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 0.0)
            self.selectionLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(rect: selectionRect).cgPath

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.roundedLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .rightBorder:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let selectionRect = selectionLayerBounds
                .insetBy(dx: selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 4)
                .offsetBy(dx: -selectionLayerWidth / 4, dy: 0.0)
            self.selectionLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(rect: selectionRect).cgPath

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.roundedLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .single:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = false
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.roundedLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .today:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = false

            let diameter: CGFloat = min(roundedLayerHeight, roundedLayerWidth)
            let rect = CGRect(x: contentWidth / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              y: contentHeight / 2 - diameter / 2,
                              width: diameter,
                              height: diameter)
                .insetBy(dx: 2.5, dy: 2.5)
            self.todayLayer?.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect).cgPath

        case .none:
            self.selectionLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.roundedLayer?.isHidden = true
            self.todayLayer?.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

I have referred lot of stuffs in the stackoverflow and some where else but i could't found the proper result any where.

[image: Here is the result i'm looking for]

I also had a look at the above like and some reference but in that case i have the issue of random date selected in the some other random months.

Comment: I got the code , let me check and get back to you sir.

Comment: Also i have one query with you about how to post the questions properly , bcoz previously you have edited my code to the good way , i also tried to place like that but i can't please let me know what you have done

Comment: for image this is format ![](image url goes here), you had [](image url). To forrmat code, paste and press Command+K

Comment: I took a look at the code that you provided to me , its very useful i need to understand about the work flow , also need to change some things based on my need like the corner radius stuffs and all.

Comment: I give working code which I used before 3 years ago I think...

Comment: Yes , i'm a beginner so it looks like pretty good for me thanks fahim. if any query means i'll reach you

Comment: hy Fahim kindly check it out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624089/fscalendar-rangeselection-with-calayer-swift

Comment: mark this question as closed or delete it...

Comment: @NaveenKumar can you share the code?